# Convert from matplotlib to ggplot2 within python

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-ggplot

I have build framework to do some algorithm evaluation. I have build methods to calculate based on data that I am passing into these method. RMSE@K, NDCG@K, MAE@K etc.

```
ndcg = []
rmse = []
mae = []
for i in xrange(11):
    results = generate_metrics(data_file, i)
    ndcg.append(np.mean(results['ndcg']))
    rmse.append(np.mean(results['rmse']))
    mae.append(np.mean(results['mae']))
plt.plot(ndcg)
plt.plot(rmse)
plt.plot(mae)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

I want to use ggplot within python to plot this in one graph: X axis is @k values which is 0-10 and y axis relevant value in each list.

how can I convert above lists to a data frame like this:

```
   at_k      ndcg      rmse       mae
1     1 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
2     2 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
3     3 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
4     4 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
5     5 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
6     6 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
7     7 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
8     8 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
9     9 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
10   10 0.4880583 0.3438043 0.3400933
```

and plot it using ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating some random data in the same form as your dataset using

```
import numpy as np
ndcg, rmse, mae = [], [], []
for i in xrange(11):
    rand = np.random.sample(3)
    ndcg.append(rand[0])
    rmse.append(rand[1])
    mae.append(rand[2])
```

I can create a Pandas DataFrame from it:

```
    import pandas as pd
at_k = range(1, 12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"at_k": at_k, "ndcg": ndcg, "rmse": rmse, "mae": mae})
print df
```

This outputs

```
    at_k       mae      ndcg      rmse
0      1  0.153102  0.546553  0.794357
1      2  0.882718  0.342260  0.762997
2      3  0.153298  0.695626  0.581455
3      4  0.073772  0.491996  0.384631
4      5  0.014066  0.369490  0.606842
5      6  0.892553  0.818312  0.396829
6      7  0.143114  0.739370  0.812050
7      8  0.847054  0.323221  0.932366
8      9  0.122838  0.613340  0.393237
9     10  0.645705  0.486312  0.138259
10    11  0.339063  0.223995  0.115242
```

Yay! But we can't use this for plotting with yhat's ggplot yet. Following [this example](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot#examples), we need to transform the data:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df[['at_k', 'mae', 'ndcg', 'rmse']], id_vars=['at_k'])
print df2
```

Now we've got something like this (truncated):

```
    at_k variable     value
0      1      mae  0.153102
1      2      mae  0.882718
2      3      mae  0.153298
3      4      mae  0.073772
...
30     9     rmse  0.393237
31    10     rmse  0.138259
32    11     rmse  0.115242
```

Now it's the time to plot:

```
ggplot(aes(x='at_k', y='value', colour='variable'), data=df2) +\
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, I am going to switch geom_point with geom_line()